# Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel missing

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, excel-2007

I'm currently rewriting an older AddIn for Excel 2007 that another developer write about 2 years ago. But when I want to debug it in VS 2008, the following error occurs;

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 6   36  E:\..\doc.cs
```

I have Offie 2007 installed, as well as Power tools and virtually any package I could find when searching the internet for this assembly. But nothing contained it.

So now I desperately ask for your help on where to get this assembly from...

Comment: It is not Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel that is missing but Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Extensions. See ServiceGuy's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Extensions` is from VSTO 2005 SE and doesn't work in VSTO 3.0 or higher. If it's not working in VS 2008, that means you have VSTO 3.0 installed and are targeting it.

- **Solution**: Make sure you have 
  Visual Studio 2008 SP1 installed
  (yes, ***VS2008 SP1***, ***not***
  only **.NET 3.5 SP1** or **VSTO 3.0 SP1**). This will fix the issue. Download here: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (Installer)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)

Comment: This fixed it, now there are just some errors in the code itself, but I think the reference itself is established now..

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 and still have this issue

Answer (score 3):

It was only added to SP1 of VSTO 3.0 which you can get here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d8eb4921-891a-4b5e-973f-0b96e6ccf376.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to look at Visual Studio Tools for Office

[VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d.aspx)

That might have the assembly you need.

Comment: I downloaded all VSTO I could find and upon installing it tells me that I "already have another version of this software installed" - So I figured it must already be installed in VS 2008